# Stop Preview.app window from resizing to content on open?

Tags: mac, images, preview

Is there a way to make Preview stop resizing to the size of the image I open?  Kind of making me nuts.  I just want it to stay the same size and scale the image to fit.

If it's not possible, feel free to tell me.

Comment: I don't understand. You want it to stay the same size, but you want it to scale the image to fit? Those two things seem mutually exclusive.

Comment: I want the Preview window to stay the same size.  I want the image to scale to fit the Preview window.

Answer (score 1):

Preview will open the file at 100% view size, unless your screen isn’t big enough in which case it will scale it to fit.

I can see why you might want a PDF to open at larger sizes, but for a bitmap image surely 100% is generally the size you want to see it at?